# Extend JWT Token : Add role to Principal/Token for Okta integrated Keycloak JWT token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, keycloak, okta

I have configured Okta in Keycloak (10.0.0) Identity Provider using OpenId Connect v1.0. So that users can login via keycloak and JWT token will be generated by keycloak.

Keycloak User is created by Admin. User details and Role is saved in Keycloak server by using keycloak-admin-client. But Okta SSO users are external to the platform. For Okta users on first time login their details will be saved in the keycloak server (without role).

In Spring Security configured looks something like below

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
/**
 * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new CustomKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

//May be I can use NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy here as the application is used to authorize api request only using token
@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}
 
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .and().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and().authorizeRequests()         
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
        
}
.....

// Avoid double bean registration
//...
//registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Keycloak JWT token has role while Okta token has no role in the realm_access. So I'm unable to use @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_PM')") (for Okta user it will fail).

**Keycloak (extract from token): Our application users** (Created by app-admin)

```
"realm_access": {
 "roles": [
   "offline_access",
   "ROLE_MANAGER",
   "uma_authorization"
 ]
}
```

**Keycloak token (extract from token): For Okta SSO users** (External to our application)

```
"realm_access": {
 "roles": [
   "offline_access",
   "uma_authorization"
 ]
}
```

Expecting: **extend the Keycloak token or Principal to add Role from DB to Okta user token**. So that I can use @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')") on Controller methods.

I have found a link: [Extend Keycloak token in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694415/extend-keycloak-token-in-spring-boot)

But there token authentication work is overridden. I don't know if there will any security concern in future or the code can be used on production !

Comment: The keycloak adapters for Spring where deprecated a year ago and are not compatible with Spring boot 3. Don't use it. Also, You write "Okta token(extract from token)" when it clearly looks like a Keycloak token. What is your intention exactly? Does Okta send roles to Keycloak or do you expect Keycloak to attach roles to an Okta identity?

Comment: @ch4mp I have updated the question related to user and role. Keycloak and it's users are managed by us, where as Okta users are external to our system (Token is managed by Keycloak). For Okta users on first time login their details will be saved in keycloak without Role. So I need to extend the token or principal in our spring security  and authorization. Authentication is done by react app. Spring-Boot app is just a restful service.

Comment: I would rather update roles in Keycloak database once (for a user) so that all tokens are emitted with the right value. How do you know which roles should be assigned to which Okta user?